# Проблема с кодировкой в node.js + mssql + utf8

Tags: node.js, sql-server

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

**Проблема:** в Таблицу msql падает белиберда вот такая:

```
id  sender  receiver    msg date
32  =4@59   >1  @825B <8@   2020-10-07 13:20:28.883
31  =4@59   >1  @8<5B <8@   2020-10-07 13:12:58.617
```

Разумеется если сделать INSERT в MSSQL Management Studio, то данные падают корректно.

**Окружение:** тестовое на openserver, Винда MSSQL 2008 R2

Есть вот такой javascript код:

```
var sql = require('mssql');
const config = {
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    server: '192.168.0.1',
    database: 'dbname',
    port:   1433,
    "options": {
        "encrypt": false,
        "enableArithAbort": true
    },
    char_set: 'utf8'

};

var connection = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
var req = new sql.Request(connection);
connection.connect(function (err) {
    if(err){
        // errors of connections if any
        console.log('connection: ',err);
        return;
    }
    var sender = 'Андрей';
    var receiver = 'Боб';
    var msg = "Какой то текст на русском";
    req
        .input('sender',sql.VarChar(20),sender)
        .input('receiver',sql.VarChar(20),receiver)
        .input('msg',sql.VarChar(20),msg)
        .execute('chatTest',(err,result)=>{
            if(err)
                console.log(err)
            else
                console.log(result)
            connection.close()
    })
});
```

Таблица "dbname" SQL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dbname](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [sender] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [receiver] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [msg] [text] NOT NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Сама процедура "chatTest"

```
USE [dbname]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[chatTest]

@sender varchar(10),
@receiver varchar(10),
@msg TEXT

AS

INSERT INTO chat2 (sender,receiver,msg,date) 
        VALUES (@sender,@receiver,@msg,getdate())
```

Comment: какая версия SQL-server?

Comment: ver: MSSQL 2008 r2

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил переводом типа строковых данных из varchar в nvarchar.